# Starting from any item position in a array with jquery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

Can I start looping from the 3rd item, or any other item, in an array with the jquery `$.each()`and also with  `$(elem).each()`. I want both examples. `#tableau` is the id of a `<table>` in HTML.
See my code below:

```
var tableau = $('#tableau'), 
    tds = tableau.find('td'),
    tdLen = tds.length,
    superMarios = [
                    'Super Mario Bros', 
                    'Super Mario Bros 2', 
                    'Super Mario Bros 3', 
                    'Super Mario World',
                    'Super Mario World 2: Yoshi\'s Island',
                    'Super Mario Galaxy', 
                    'New Super Mario Bros Wii', 
                    'Super Mario Galaxy 2'
                 ],
    superMarioCollection = superMarios.length;

$.each(superMarios, function(i, val){
  console.log(i + ': ' + val);
  tds.eq(i).append(val);
});
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't start from anything but `0` with `$.each()`, but you can prevent the code inside from running by using an `if()` statement.

```
$.each(superMarios, function(i, val){
  if( i >= 2 ) {
      console.log(i + ': ' + val);
      tds.eq(i).append(val);
  }
});
```

---

Or if you want to start on the third, but you want the indices to start with `0`, then just take a `.slice()` of the Array, giving it the zero-based index where you want to begin.

```
$.each(superMarios.slice( 2 ), function(i, val){
  console.log(i + ': ' + val);
  tds.eq(i).append(val);
});
```

---

Or as an alternate to the first example, just offset the `i` the same amount as your starting point to give you the higher starting index:

```
var idx = 2;
$.each(superMarios.slice( idx ), function(i, val){
   console.log((i+idx) + ': ' + val);
   tds.eq(i+idx).append(val);
});
```

Comment: I came here to suggest the `slice` approach.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Instead, you should use an ordinary `for` loop.

Comment: +1.  I agree.  `jQuery.each()` should only be used when it's better or more convenient than a native `for` loop.  In this case it is not better so a native `for` loop where directly control the starting point is definitely better here.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot tell `$.each` to start at a certain index, you can [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) your array before passing it to `$.each`:

```
$.each(superMarios.slice(2), function(i, val){
  console.log(i + ': ' + val);
  tds.eq(i).append(val);
});
```

**Note:** `slice` will not effect your original array. Rather, it'll return a copy of a portion of your array.